# Server side JavaScript action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I coded a chat script using AJAX.NET. For every button click I am using the following sample of code in which I am using `OnClientClick` function to scroll down on every button click i.e. update.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_msg" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_msg_Click" OnClientClick="scrolldown('div1')" />
```

This results fine on the page I am working but in the receiver side scroll bar is not getting down on update. I guess changing the option `OnClientClick` to some server action will help. I tried adding `OnClick="btn_msg_Click; scrolldown('div1');"` but this is not working. Is there any alternate way to fulfill my action.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I believe Anton is correct.  The reason you are seeing this behavior is the order in which everythings runs.  The client script runs first.  Then the server script.  The server script causes a postback( or even via an update panel ), causing it to render the html again, losing the scroll bar position.

Anton's code causes the scrolldown function to run once the ajax postback is complete.

A side note:
If I were doing this, I'd remove the AJAX.NET completely and switch to jquery.  You have a lot more control over this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook on the endCallback event to scrolldown.
The moment you try to scroll down content is not yet delivered.

Try it this way:

```
<body onload=”load()”>
<script>
function EndRequestHandler()
{
    scrolldown('div1');
}

function load() 
{
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, completely misunderstood the question. Check out the updated version.